# a + adjective + "many" + of the + plural noun

Tags: pronouns, prepositional-phrases, countable-nouns

> (Countable noun) [a + adjective + ~ **+ of the + plural noun**] a large number of persons
> or things:
>
> *A good **many** of the beggars were blind.*
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/definition/many

Is the plural nominal complement compulsory, so that *A good **many** were blind* is not grammatically correct?

Secondly, is it correct to label it as a "countable noun"?

Comment: First, _many_ is not an adjective; it's a quantifier. Second, very few adjectives work here; you can say _a good many_, but not *_a big many,_ *_a blue many_, *_a bad many_, etc. Third, words do not add together like beads on a string -- there are constructions involved and writing strings of ill-understood labels with plus signs does not describe anything.

Comment: @JohnLawler What PoS does _quantifier_ refer to? Also, your comment dealt with neither of my questions in the OP

Comment: _Quantifier_ **is** a part of speech. It's usually considered a variety of determiner. Though what PoS one should call intermediate nodes in a derivation is not an empirical matter.

Comment: @JohnLawler it's the nominal use which I am referring to in the OP